# C# how to get the selected column ID value from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and users can select columns. I want that selected column to pass the value of the ID attribute. I tried quite a few different ways, but always came back with error. Usual error message - "Index was out of range". Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection...

few of the lines I tried

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0]);
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected);
```

Comment: Please clarify your requirement. "I want that selected column to pass the value of the ID attribute" - columns do not have "value".

Comment: You are right, sorry. Every column's first cell is the id of the student which i need to get to pass it on

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. All I can say is that the selected columns can be accessed via [DataGridView.SelectedColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: If I use `SelectedColumns` how can I get the value of the first cell? I can not find such an option.

Comment: Cell is an intersection of row and column. Hence a column contains multiple cells. Same for row. You'd better update your question with a concrete example presenting the use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Int id= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value);
```

"datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index" gets the index of selected row.

Comment: Simply: `int id = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;`

Answer (score 1):

Selected columns haven't information about selected rows, so you can just loop all rows to get your ID.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvr.Cells[0].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That exception means that you have no selection and `SelectedRows` collection is empty. Instead of `[0]` use [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) like `.FirstOrDefault()?.`

Comment: I tried it but I could not get it working. It didnt even come up with the option `FirstOrDefult()`. However I dont need a default. I only need this ID when the user selects a column and then I need the first cell's value which is the ID of the student