# select multiple rows from datagridview and show the IDs

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm doing a simple quiz program.

Here's how my program works: User can choose from two options;

- either choose only one category(DropDownList)
- choosing multiple category(where multiple rows are selected from the DataGridView)

For now I just want that if user choose multiple rows, all the IDs of the rows selected must be shown in MsgBox(). Is there anyway that I can do it? Thank you in advance.

**Edited**

Okay, so far I have this:

```
Dim id, i, j As Integer
Dim idList(1)
For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In qstSets.SelectedRows
    'show ids of multiple selected rows
    id = qstSets.SelectedRows(0).Cells("ID").Value
    idList(i) = id
    i += 1
Next selectedItem
For j = 0 To 1
     MsgBox("Element " & j & " = " & idList(j))
Next j
```

I have planned to safe the id's of selected row in array and then display it. But the problem here is that, I keep getting only one id in the Element when I have selected 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*:

Thank you for your help @cyril

```
Dim id, i As Integer
Dim idList(5)
For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In qstSets.SelectedRows
    'show ids of multiple selected rows
    id = selectedItem.Cells("ID").Value
    idList(i) = id
    i += 1
Next selectedItem
Dim sResult As String = ""
For Each elem As String In idList
    sResult &= elem & ", "
Next
MsgBox(sResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all selected datagridview rows:

```
For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
```

For getting the Id or any value you like, please have a look to:
[DataGridView get column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704959/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-selected-column-id-value-from-datagridview)

Comment: id = qstSets.SelectedRows(0).Cells("ID").Value , should be 
 id = selectedItem.Cells("ID").Value

Answer (score 0):

**To show ID's and select Multiple rows in datagridview I think it would be helpful to You.**

```
Dim SelectedRow as datagridview.selectedrow(0)
Dim selectedID as selectedRow.cells("ID").value
Dim Row as Datarow
Dim IDLists as List(of integer)
For i = 1 To datagridview.SelectedRows.Count()
     selectedRow = datagridview.SelectedRows(i - 1)
     selectedID = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value
      row = _table.Select("ID =" & selectedID).FirstOrDefault()
      IDlists.add(selectedID)
Next
for j = 0 to IDLists.count
   messagebox.show(IDlists(j))
Next
```

**I think This will be helpful If I am wrong correct me**